# Update Manager Table Tree by Recursion

Tags: t-sql, recursion, sql-server-2008-r2, sum, with-statement

I have a table (*see image*) Employees (manager is manager of another and so on) with id, parentid, salary, **totalsalary**. The last one needs to be updated so that every employee had Sum of its Descendants salary. I have already written script, which gets total salary by id and than updates column in cursor, but it's heavy... any other ways?

```
DECLARE @id INT ;
DECLARE @s INT ;
DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR
SELECT personid FROM dbo.Employees
OPEN curs ;
FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @id ;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        WITH    Xemps ( ID )
                  AS ( SELECT   PersonID AS ID
                       FROM     dbo.Employees
                       WHERE    PersonID = @id
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT   e.PersonID AS ID
                       FROM     dbo.Employees AS e
                                INNER JOIN Xemps AS x ON e.ManagerID = x.ID
                     )
            SELECT  @s = SUM(Salary)
            FROM    dbo.Employees
            WHERE   PersonID IN ( SELECT    id
                                  FROM      Xemps )
        UPDATE  dbo.Employees
        SET     SalarySum = @s
        WHERE   PersonID = @id
        FETCH NEXT FROM curs INTO @id
    END
CLOSE curs ;
DEALLOCATE curs ;
```

[image: this is my test table of Employees]

Comment: Please tag with your SQL Server version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cursor is not necessary, this can be done using just a recursive common table expression:

```
WITH Emp AS
(   SELECT  EmployeeID, Salary, ManagerID
    FROM    dbo.Employee
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  e.EmployeeID, e.Salary, Emp.ManagerID
    FROM    dbo.Employee e
            INNER JOIN Emp
                ON e.ManagerID = Emp.EmployeeID
)
UPDATE  dbo.Employee
SET     SalarySum = COALESCE(s.Salary, 0) + e.Salary
FROM    dbo.Employee e
        LEFT JOIN 
        (   SELECT  ManagerID, SUM(Salary) [Salary]
            FROM    Emp
            GROUP BY ManagerID
        ) s
            ON s.ManagerID = e.EmployeeID
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that performs the sum for each employee where they are a manager:

```
create function dbo.fn_TotalSalary    
{
  @EmployeeId int
} 
returns float
as
begin

  declare @totalSalary float

  select @totalSalary = sum(salary)
  from dbo.employees 
  where employeeid = @employeeid or managerid = @employeeid

  return @totalSalary 
end
```

Then alter the Employees table, changing the TotalSalary column to a computed column using the function:

```
dbo.fn_TotalSalary(EmployeeId)
```

As employees earn more, the computed column will update automatically.  Then you can simply call

```
select * from Employees
```

to get the details.  Doing it this way would mean that your data is always 100% accurate and up to date rather than potentially retrieving stale data.